# SBJson parser unhappy with [Ô]

Tags: iphone, json

I'm having issues finding out what's wrong with the json string I receive from http://www.hier-bin-ich-koenig.de/json/events to be able to parse it. It doesn't validate, at least not with jsonlint, but I don't know where the issue is. So of course SBJson is unhappy too.

I also don't understand where that [Ô] is coming from. I'd love to know if it's from the content or the code that's converting the content into json. Being able to find where the validation error is would be great.

The exact error sent by the tokeniser is:

JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [Ô]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your page includes a UTF-16 BOM (byte order mark), followed by a UTF-8 encoded document. You should drop the BOM entirely. It is not recommended for UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was parsing a json string which was generated by a PHP page. I resolved this problem by using Notepad++,

1, open the php file.
2, menu -> encoding -> encode UTF8 without BOM
3, save.

that's done.[image]